# Why is my React state hook (setState) so picky about the array I give it?

Tags: react-hooks, mutation

There is something about state hooks in React that I don't understand. I am dealing with the following situation in my code:

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(["foo"])  

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myArray has been updated")
}, [myArray])

const clickUpdate = () => {
    var myUpdatedArray = myArray
    myUpdatedArray.push("bar")
    setMyArray(myUpdatedArray)
}
```

This does **not** work. Calling the `clickUpdate` does not update `myArray`.

The problem is in the `clickUpdate` function. When I rewrite the function in the following way it works just fine:

```
...

const clickUpdate = () => {
    var myUpdatedArray = [...myArray, "bar"]
    setMyArray(myUpdatedArray)
}
```

or alternatively:

```
...

const clickUpdate = () => {
    setMyArray(myArray=> [...myArray, "bar])
}
```

Either solution works for me just fine, but I am curious:

What is it about the `.push` mutation of `myUpdatedArray` that makes my `setMyArray` not work properly? Or what else is going on here that I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

React compares the values in the deps array by reference, that's way it works when you create a new array.

If you are just going to add/remove items (not editing them) then you can be more performant and pass myArray.length to the deps list. Thus react will detect changes when the length is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myArray has been updated")
}, [myArray.length])
```